# Kubuntu 15.04 how to permanently edit dolphin or yakuake profile

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04, yakuake

The problem is the same in yakuake and dolphin.

In the previous versions of kubuntu, I changed yakuake colors. To do so I had to close yakuake, edit my profile in a konsole window and restart yakuake.

With kubuntu 15.04 the modifications are only applied to konsole and not to yakuake. I can directly edit my profile in yakuake but the modifications are not saved (the colors will be reseted next time yakuake is launched).

Do you know how to permanently apply that kind of modifications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the appearance of the terminal window in yakuake is controlled by the konsole KPart component. The settings of konsole are stored in

```
~/.kde4/share/config/konsolerc
```

In order to make that work you should do two things:

1. Locate the profile configuration for yakuake and remember the file name

   ```
   ~/.local/share/yakuake/somename.profile
   ```
2. Add this name to the konsole configuration like this:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   DefaultProfile=somename.profile

   [Favorite Profiles]
   Favorites=somename.profile
   ```

Note that there might be other parts in your konsole configuration. Just add the metioned sections.

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests and found a solution by luck:
- create the folder : ~/.local/share/dolphin
- add in this folder the .colorscheme file I usually use
- edit in dolphin and yakuake the profile (Edit profile > Appearance > Select the corresponding color scheme)

I have no idea why it is working (especially for yakuake since I did not create a "yakuake" folder) but it works...